# Problems with Big-M Constraint

Tags: modeling, integer-programming, constraint, logical-constraints, big-m

I have the following constraints for my roster optimisation problem:
\begin{align}
    &(1-r_{i,t})\le \sum_{j=t-\chi}^{t-1}sc_{i,j}\quad &\forall i\in I, t\in \{1+\chi,\ldots,T\}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&M\cdot (1-r_{i,t})\ge \sum_{j=t-\chi}^{t-1}sc_{i,j}\quad &\forall i\in I, t\in \{1+\chi,\dots,T\}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&r_{i,t}=0\quad &\forall i\in I, t\in \{1,\ldots,\chi\}
\end{align}
It is intended to ensure that the binary variable $r_{it}$ assumes the value one if the binary variable $sc_{i,t}$ was always zero in the previous $\chi$ days (there was no shift change in the last $\chi$ days). Otherwise, $r_{i,t}=0$ should apply if there was such a shift change. The variable $r_{i,t}$ is then used in the model to enable work performance to be restored. Now to my question / problem.

1. Is it possible to improve / summarise the three constraints?
2. Main problem: The variable $r_{i,t}$ can also take the value of 1 in this modelling if, for example, there was no change on the first three days ($t=1-3$). However, I actually want to model that this possible assignment of $r_{i,t}$ is only possible from the first shift change in the planning horizon. In other words, only once $sc_{i,t}=1$ has applied.

Example 1:
$\chi=2$ applies. $sc_{i,t}=[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]$, then it currently follows that$r_{i,t}= [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1]$.

Example 2 (as it should be): $\chi=2$ applies.
$sc_{i,t}=[0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]$, then it should follow:
$r_{i,t}= [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are enforcing:
   \begin{align}
   \lnot sc_{t-\chi}\land\dots\land \lnot sc_{t-1} \implies r_t 
   &\equiv \lnot (\lnot sc_{t-\chi}\land\dots\land \lnot sc_{t-1}) \lor r_t \\
   &\equiv (sc_{t-\chi}\lor\dots\lor sc_{t-1}) \lor r_t \\
   &\equiv sc_{t-\chi}+\dots+sc_{t-1}+r_t \ge 1 \\
   &\equiv 1-r_t \le sc_{t-\chi}+\dots+sc_{t-1}
   \end{align}
   which is your first constraint.

You are also enforcing:
\begin{align}
 sc_{t-\chi}\lor\dots\lor sc_{t-1} \implies \lnot r_t 
&\equiv \lnot ( sc_{t-\chi}\lor\dots\lor  sc_{t-1}) \lor \lnot r_t \\
&\equiv (\lnot sc_{t-\chi}\land\dots\land \lnot sc_{t-1}) \lor \lnot r_t \\
&\equiv \land_{k=t-\chi}^{t-1} (\lnot sc_k \lor \lnot r_t) \\
&\equiv 1-sc_{k}+1-r_t \ge 1 &&\forall k=t-\chi,\dots,t-1\\
&\equiv sc_k \le 1-r_t &&\forall k=t-\chi,\dots,t-1\\
\end{align}
This is the disaggregated version of your second constraint (tighter), with $M=\chi$.

2. If my understanding is correct (?), you want to enforce:
   $$
   (\lnot sc_{t-\chi}\land\dots\land \lnot sc_{t-1}) \land sc_t \implies r_t 
   $$
   Using the same methodology:
   \begin{align}
   \lnot sc_{t-\chi}\land\dots\land \lnot sc_{t-1} \land sc_t \implies r_t
   &\equiv \lnot (\lnot sc_{t-\chi}\land\dots\land \lnot sc_{t-1} \land  sc_t) \lor r_t \\
   &\equiv (sc_{t-\chi}\lor\dots\lor sc_{t-1} \lor \lnot sc_t) \lor r_t \\
   &\equiv sc_{t-\chi}+\dots+sc_{t-1}+(1-sc_t)+r_t \ge 1 \\
   &\equiv sc_t \le sc_{t-\chi}+\dots+sc_{t-1}+r_t
   \end{align}